# How do I secure my sump discharge pipe?

Tags: pipe, sump

I had about 20' of pipe coming out of the house that gave out after 6 years. I wanted to know what's the best way to secure it in place to keep it secure from movement. I temporarily put two stakes with a screw zip tie.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Burial is a good way, and also gets it out of the sunlight that destroys PVC pipe.

Comment: What sort of movement are you trying to prevent, and is this a temporary fix until springtime (based on the snow in your photo), or are you looking for a permanent fix?

Comment: Burial (below the frost line) will also prevent the sump water from freezing in the pipe which would prevent the sump pump from being able to do its job.

Comment: Burial is currently not an option. In the interim, I'm looking for a way to ensure the pipe doesn't move due to wildlife or someone tripping on it.